# Visual Studio Installer Projects for 2013 -- can't uninstall a program on Windows 8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2013, registry, windows-installer, uninstallation

I'm trying to use this Visual Studio extension for 2013, which recreates the built-in installer functionality from Visual Studio 2008/2010: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2014/04/17/visual-studio-installer-projects-extension.aspx?CommentPosted=true&PageIndex=2#comments

It works, allowing me to edit the project as before.  It has the install and uninstall commands when right-clicking the install project, too.  It installs fine.

When I try to uninstall, though, I get the following error and then the uninstall rolls back:

```
Could not open key: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE32\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\
EAPSIMMethods\18\FastReauthContext.  Verify that you have sufficient 
access to that key, or contact your support personnel.
```

I am not doing anything with that registry key, and there don't seem to be any relevant results on google-- at least not in the normal top 5 pages.  Does anyone know what causes this or how I can fix it?

While I am not able to uninstall, I am able to increment the version of the package and allow it to remove the previous install and install the new version (all at once) successfully.

I am using Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit, the projects are compiled for `<AnyCPU>`, and the installer is configured for x86.

**EDIT** I am running Visual Studio as Admin.  When uninstalling from the Control Panel, I am also clicking the 'allow' button in the UAC dialog window that pops up.

I know how to give myself access to a registry key (permissions).  I want to know *why* this key is trying to be removed.  I support this app on several machines and I don't want to have worry about remembering an uninstall hack in the future.

**EDIT** This only seems to be an issue for a 32x installer on a 64x OS or a Windows 8 issue.  I was able to use the same 32x installer to successfully uninstall the app on a 32x Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Do you have any custom actions that might be touching this key? That includes service install or any installer classes or other code that runs. Have you added any merge modules that might reference this key? You could open the MSI file with Orca from the Windows SDK and search for that item to see if it's in there somehow.

Comment: No, I have no custom actions.  There's nothing special to this-- it just adds a few registry keys so I can track the installation location.  Those keys are new for my app, nothing else is touched.  I had no problem with this until I tried to use the extension mentioned in the question.  VS 2010-compiled installers had no issue with this.

Answer (score 1):

This must be an environmental problem, that key doesn't have anything to do with installers.  EAP-SIM is an authentication protocol for wireless networks.  The FastReauthContext key almost surely was meant to avoid having to provide a username+password each time your machine reconnects to the network.  Which makes the registry key content very sensitive of course, it can only be read by a service that runs with the System account.

So, something goofy going on with your networking setup.  Verify that you can successfully reconnect to such a network.  If you used a VPN before then make sure it is active again.  Something like this.  Update your question with anything that *might* be relevant to networking when you first installed the app.

Comment: I am on my domain network.  I can't even take control of those registry keys in order to run the uninstall.  I'm not sure why the app won't let me uninstall because of some network credentials.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problem and what I found out this is caused by MSI attempting to delete whole "Software\Microsoft" section in the registry. Lucky you that it encounters this error and rolls everything back.
So the solution is the following:

1. Since you have installed your program whenever you try to uninstall it the system will run msi from cache that is usually located C:\Windows\Installer.
2. Find your package in the cache. Here is an article that may help you http://csi-windows.com/blog/all/27-csi-news-general/334-identifying-cached-msi-packages-in-cwindowsinstaller-without-opening-them
3. Open the package in Orca. You must do this as administrator.
4. Go to Registry table and find record with "Software\Microsoft" as a key. Most likely the Name column will contain either "-" or "*" value. This means that during uninstall MSI will try to delete whole "Software\Microsoft".
5. Either change the Name value to empty or "+" or try to change key to something like "Microsoft". The second option will cause that installer will not find the key to delete during uninstall, but it will skip this error and let you uninstall your program.

Comment: did you find the reason why the MSI was doing that? I just did a rebuild of an existing old MSI. And I'm having the exact same issue now.

Comment: If you have windows MSI installer project (the old one from VS 2015) check registry editor and check DeleteAtUninstall property for HKLM/Software/Microsoft key. If it is True, then you need to change it to False.

Comment: Thanks for the response. We add "HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Silverlight\AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser" and "HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Silverlight\AllowElevatedTrustAppsInBrowser". But on all keys we have "DeleteAtUninstall"=False.

Comment: The key itself may have this property set to False, but try to check for every parent key (folder icon in UI)

Answer (score -1):

You installed an untested installer on your dev machine? Speaking from experience, don't do that!  Snapshotted VM's are cheap and will save you from this sort of pain.

Visual Studio Deployment Projects (or VSI as it's now called ) is known for creating very poor quality installs.  The combination of those two put you where you are today.

I would need to look at the full uninstall log and your MSI using ORCA to understand exactly what is going on.  MSI Zap and a manual cleanup of resources is probably required at this point.